# lighttpd reverse proxy | http://xxx:port -> http://xxx/catalog/index.html

Tags: redirect, proxy, url-rewriting, reverse, lighttpd

I've got question regarding to proxy.

I have got content on xxx:port (its live stream from motion raspberry pi). I would like to get it public but motion doesn't provide any auth method right now (was in previous build but no ATM...) I would like to redirect traffic destined to http://xxx:port to my secure catalog on raspberry too http://xxx/catalog/index.html.

I am not experienced in lighttpd, I was trying to search examples here and on google but these examples was related to site <-> site proxy, not port -> catalog.

Thank You in advance :)
MacieX

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your just looking for a simple redirect.

Enable mod_redirect in your lighttpd.conf.

```
server.modules = (
    .
    "mod_redirect", ## uncomment or add this line
    "mod_rewrite",
    .
    .
    .
)
```

And then add the following to the end of the file...

```
 $SERVER["socket"] == ":8080" {
    url.redirect = (
        ".*" => "http://example.com/catalog/index.html"
    )
 }
```

This will redirect requests to port 8080 to your catalog.